# MaterializeCSS e conflitos com jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, front-end, materialize

Eu estou com um problema aqui usando o Materialize CSS e duas versões do jQuery. 
Eu estou fazendo um site onepage, e eu coloquei o smooth scrolling effect(eu peguei neste site aqui > http://www.learningjquery.com/2007/10/improved-animated-scrolling-script-for-same-page-links ) e ele usa uma versão diferente do jQuery 3.1.1 (no qual usa o Materialize uses). Então, quando eu deixo o jQuery 3.1.1 ativo no codigo, os efeitos do JS do Materialize funcionam, mas quando eu deixo o jQuery 2.1.1(usado pelo smooth scrolling) ativado, o smooth scrolling para de funcionar. Eu tentei usar o metodo "no conficts" do jQuery, mas isso não funcionou também.

Comment: Você já viu a resposta desse link? [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566595/can-i-use-multiple-versions-of-jquery-on-the-same-page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566595/can-i-use-multiple-versions-of-jquery-on-the-same-page)

Comment: Funcionou! Valeu cara